# How to force emacs projectile to reinitialize a project?

Tags: emacs, projectile

I'm using projectile with emacs to manage a large project.

I moved a number of directories with scores of files.

The old file paths are still showing up in projectile find file (C-c p f).

How do I remove them in bulk or force projectile to re-initialize the project?

I've tried:

- projectile-purge-dir-from-cache
- projectile-invalidate-cache
- quitting emacs, deleting ~/.emacs.d/projectile.cache, restarting emacs
- adding a .projectile file with 'exclude' options for the original dirs

After all of these, the same original list of old paths/files still appears on C-c p f.

Comment: How about deleting `~/.emacs.d/projectile.cache` and using either `ag`(the silver searcher) or `rg` (ripgrep) to generate the project files ? Check out my [projectile config](https://github.com/CSRaghunandan/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-projectile.el) to get an idea on how you can use `rg` to generate project files

Comment: Have you tried `C-u C-c p f`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`C-u C-c p f` does it.

Thanks to Daimrod!

Comment: What is the name of the command this keybinding is pointing to?

Comment: @bobsacameno the command `C-c p f` is `projectile-find-file` the `C-u` command says to run `projectile-find-file` with a different behavior.  In this case the new behavior is to clear the cache first.  If you read the documentation `C-h o projectile-find-file` you will see `(projectile-find-file &optional INVALIDATE-CACHE)`.  The `C-u` activates the "optional" argument.

Comment: @RickyNelson in my emacs (doom) I have that `C-u` scrolls up, so I am not sure what should substitute this.

Comment: @bobsacameno Should be `SPC u`

Comment: @bobsacameno I get the message: `SPC u is undefined`. 
In my evil emacs, I go to insert-mode and then press `C-u`. That works

Answer (score 4):

As answered [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12843/how-to-clear-cache-of-projectile-file-in-spacemacs), you can simply call `projectile-invalidate-cache` to clear the old cache files for the current project.

This is `SPC-p-i` in Doom Emacs or `M-x projectile-invalidate-cache` in regular Emacs.